# How to change standard value of GDB debugger in eclipse-cdt programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am a completely newbie in Eclipse and in Eclipse-CDT in particular, so I ask for your help.

In

> Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB

we have standart value "gdb" in the "GDB Debugger" field. 
I want to change this value. I mean, I have a plugin which should change the value "gdb" at the beginning of the plugin's run.
But I don't know which plugins fill the field "GDB Debugger" and other field.

Can you help me? Can you describe the mechanism of launching and what methods are filled by these fields? Or give me some links where I can find suitable information.

Here is a picture of `Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB`:

[image: Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to find which plugin contributes to UI.

GDB Debugger field is created inside `GdbDebuggerPreferencePage`

[image]